# add button to uitableviewcell and did not showed up

Tags: ios

I am adding a delete button to a `UITableViewCell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
but the button did not show up.

```
double deleteYOffset=10;
double deleteW=100;
double deleteH=100;

UIButton *deleteButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
deleteButton.frame=CGRectMake(imageXoffset, deleteYOffset, deleteW, deleteH);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Delete.png"];
[deleteButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[deleteButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[cell contentView ]addSubview:deleteButton];
```

Comment: have you tried: [cell addSubview:deleteButton];

Comment: i did. also confirm image exists.

Comment: I have also had better luck using InitWithFrame instead of allocating it and then setting the frame

Comment: Where is imageXoffset set?

Comment: OK. I figured it out. The cell was not created...

Answer (score 2):

Don't have enough rep so can't comment, but you seem to be missing imageXoffset

I copied your code with:

```
double imageXoffset = 10;
```

and was able to see the button render for my cells. Based on this, I'm guessing your offset is not set correctly and rendering the button off the view.

Also consider moving view code into a `CustomCell` class and instantiate the `CustomCell` into `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You should be able to bind your image through xCode UI and bypass having to define the offsets/ heights and widths.

Answer (score 1):

Delete.PNG is a reserved word for IOS....I changed the image to delete1 and it worked.

Comment: Ah. That explains it. I tried your code with 'Default.png' thats included and everything worked.